# Ionic 4 Google Maps plugin "failed to load optimized model at path..."

Tags: ios, google-maps, cordova-plugins, ionic4, xcode10.1

Plugin working in browser, but on ios getting

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/[User]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FABE7039-7D5D-4AAB-B4D8-3D688FCEE930/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7DA1B2E1-0DE6-4A89-8604-0EC160298BD8/[APP-NAME].app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileProto.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/[User]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FABE7039-7D5D-4AAB-B4D8-3D688FCEE930/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7DA1B2E1-0DE6-4A89-8604-0EC160298BD8/[APP-NAME].app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileProto.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/[User]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FABE7039-7D5D-4AAB-B4D8-3D688FCEE930/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7DA1B2E1-0DE6-4A89-8604-0EC160298BD8/[APP-NAME].app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileProto.omo'
```

ive tried:

1. included API keys in config.xml, package.json, set on environment through app.component
2. tried deleting StorageWithTileProto.omo
3. updated google-maps plugin version

in app.component.ts

```
import { Environment } from '@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx';

...

 initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       Environment.setEnv({
          'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_DEBUG': "[API_KEY]",
          'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_RELEASE': "[API_KEY]",
          "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "[API_KEY]",
          "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "[API_KEY]",
        });
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.authService.getToken();
      this.getUserData()
    });
  }
```

in config.xml

```
...
<preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value="[API_KEY]" />
<preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY" value="[API_KEY]" />

...

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps">
    <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="15.0.1" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
</plugin>
```

in map.component.ts

```
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  GoogleMapOptions,
  CameraPosition,
  MarkerOptions,
  Marker,
  Environment
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx';

...

constructor(
    public locationService: LocationService,
    private platform: Platform,
    private geolocation: Geolocation,
  ) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.platform.ready();
    await this.getUserLocation();
    await this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 43.0741704,
          lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      }
    });
  }
```

EXPECTED: map shown on ios device

ACTUAL: no map rendered, not even blank map

Answer (score 0):

turns out map WAS rendering, but behind the page background. set background to transparent, fixed issue. the errors that came up are unrelated and non-breaking